# What is the appropriate HTTP Status code to use in this scenario?

Tags: rest, http, http-status-codes

I'm implementing a simple API flow which involves acting as a gateway to multiple upstream APIs.

[image demonstrating the flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B732V.png)

Basically, a client provides a token to this endpoint, the server makes multiple sequential calls to APIs, gathers a bunch of information from the final call and returns it.

We receive a token, and go to `Upstream API 1`, receiving back a bunch of `Objects` associated with that token. There can be a theoretically unlimited amount of `Objects` returned.

We then comma separate the IDs of each `Object`, and go to `Upstream API 2` with those comma separated `ObjectIDs` to receive further `MetaInformation` on all of the `Objects`.

This `MetaInformation` may not be unique to each `Object`, so we can receive anywhere between 1 and the number of `Objects` `MetaInformation` back.

The intention is then for us to go to a third API with the comma separated `MetaInformationIDs`, but this upstream API can only take 10 unique `MetaInformationIDs`, meaning that we wouldn't be able to collect the information the client is expecting. We therefore are able to throw a failure case at this point without making the failing upstream request, but what HTTP status is appropriate to use?

It doesn't seem like the client has made a bad request, as they would have no way of knowing the amount of unique `MetaInformationIds` at that point, but we *would* receive a `400` status were we to make a request with >10 `MetaInformationIds`.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I forgot to mention for context that the upstream API is intending to upgrade in the future to support >10 unique IDs, hence it has been decided that for now, a multi-request solution to that API is not worth it. I wholeheartedly agree that it is a sub-optimal solution.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be for your second microservice to create batches of `MetaInformationIDs` small enough such that the call to the third microservice would succeed.  In this case, the calls would be expected to succeed, eliminating the error you described.  If you can't do something like this, then maybe you should rethink your design.  If you can do it, then as a fallback you could return a 500 server side error code, which just means that some general error happened on the server.

Comment: Agreed. The difference between 4xx and 5xx codes is that 4xx are error conditions that the caller can conceivably correct (by using a correct url, supplying the required header or not asking for a coffee from a teapot, etc), whereas 5xx are conditions that are outside of the caller's control.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the intention is for the third upstream API to support >10 unique IDs in the future, so this is unlikely to be a permanent issue, hence not implementing the multiple requests for now.

Answer (score 1):

If the 10+ MetaInformationIDs is a bad / unexpected situation to be in then the appropriate status code would be [500 Internal Server Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) - as you say, the issue isn't with the request but rather an internal constraint that can't be controlled by the client.

If it's not an exceptional circumstance, then it sounds like more of a limitation of your API that needs addressed e.g. instead of supporting a single request to the 3rd API, create enough to cover all the unique IDs that need to be processed and return a [202 Accepted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/202)

Comment: I should have mentioned. The intention is for the third upstream API to support >10 unique IDs in the future, therefore this could be considered a temporary failure case.

Comment: @BenPerry in that case a 500 is the most appropriate way to deal with the request - the server has encountered an internal error outwith the clients control. If it's a temporary issue then you could either return a message informing the client about the problem or document it somewhere that this _may_ happen.

Answer (score 0):

We use 400 response status code to indicate that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax) which does not fall according to you scenerio.

The 500 status code, or Internal Server Error, means that server cannot process the request for an unknown reason. Sometimes this code will appear when more specific 5xx errors are more appropriate which seems appropriate in your condition because your API can only take 10 unique MetaInformationIDs.